# How to get custom attribute of a category in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to get `brand_label` of a category in Magento2. Here is my code at the moment :

```
$categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($parent_category_id);
$Categories = $categoryObj->getChildrenCategories()->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', array('eq' => 1));

$categoryArray = [];

foreach($Categories as $category){
    $categoryObject->brand_label = $category->getCustomAttribute('brand_label');
    array_push($categoryArray,$categoryObject); 
}
```

The `$categoryObject->brand_label` is returning null

Comment: You can try to find the answer at Magento StackExchange, for example, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95563/magento-2-how-to-get-custom-category-attribute-on-frontend

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the data from a category by using these ways:

```
$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
$category->getData('brand_label');
```

Or:

```
$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
$category->getBrandLabel();
```

Make sure your attribute code of category is **brand_label**